# Sequelize sort query by number of children in one-to-many relationship

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

Let's say I have a model Parent that belongsToMany Children. I want to query some parent objects, and sort them so that instances of parent with the most children come first.

Likewise, is it possible to append other conditions to the children that are counted? For example, sorting parents by the number of female children under the age or 3.

What is an efficient  way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add child count pre-calculation field to the parent so u will never need to go to children object and this will make quaring very fast, also when you add a new child/delete child keep remember to increase or decrease the value in the parent.

same in the second question add tow field into parent male_child_count & female_child_count, life will be more easier :-)

Comment: I had been kicking that idea around. Is that a common solution? Where would you recommend adding that calculation? Would afterCreate and afterDelete hooks on the child object be appropriate?

Comment: yes it is a common idea in optimizing rdbms when the speed is necessary not the size

Comment: Perfect. That's reassuring. What is the pre-calculation field that mentioned in your answer? Is that the same as a beforeSave hook on the parent object?

Comment: yes i meant as pre-calculation is increasing the chide count every time you add a new child and decrease child count every time you delete existing child from the child count field in parent object